# Обработка ошибок во всём классе

Tags: c#, исключения

Идея для проекта-чат_бота следующая:
Создать несколько классов-модулей, которые не зависят друг от друга (по типу один для обработки команд, второй для отправки сообщений по таймеру и прочее (условный пример))

И мне нужно реализовать эти "модули" так, что, если в одном возникло исключение, то он отключается и пытается восстановиться, никак не влияя на работу других "модулей".

А теперь суть вопроса:

Как отследить возникновение исключения внутри класса, не оборачивая каждый метод в try-catch?

По задумке это должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
class Test {
    Test() {
        A();
        B();
        C();
    }
    void ExceptionCatcher() {
        Console.WriteLine("Я поймал исключение!");
        Restart();
    }

    void A() {
        Console.WriteLine("Ок");
    }
    void B() {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    void C() {
        Console.WriteLine("Ок");
    }
}
```

Что-то подобное реально сделать, или следует придумать что-то другое?

Comment: Ну для начала, вы нарушаете SOLID таким кодом, а именно S - единственную ответственность, ибо сейчас ваш класс отвечает за отправку сообщения, за запуск модулей, за рестарт и так далее, а должен делать что-то одно. Далее, зачем вам запуск модулей всех разом в чат боте? Обычно, запуск действий происходит по каким-то событиям, например, когда приходит новое сообщение. Сейчас вот представим, что этот код - это ваш бот, он при запуске выдаст два "Ок" в чат и одну ошибку, вы точно эту логику от него хотите?

Comment: Нет, так не получится. Там где вы не ожидаете возникновения исключения, не надо ничего оборачивать. Разберитесь с вашим кодом, решите, где могут возникать исключения, а где нет. При нормальной работе приложения исключений вообще не должно возникать, за очень редкими и ожидаемыми ситуациями. Универсального решения здесь нет и быть не должно. Отнеситесь к исключениям как к тому что помогает вам писать код правильно, а не мешает, не надо от еих избавляться ради того чтобы избавиться.

Comment: Что значит `класс пытается восстановиться `? Восстановиться от чего? Исключение не ломает класс, исключение означает, что класс не может обработать конкретный запрос. Если у ваших классов есть состояние и оно может стать несогласованным, это должно быть проверенным до изменения состояния и такое изменение также создаст исключение. По идее классы работают, обрабатывая ожидаемые запросы и бросают исключения на не ожидаемые запросы, при этом они не ломаются, восстановления не требуют и продолжают работать.

Comment: Единственное, что мне нужно от подобного решения - избавиться от ситуаций, когда исключение в одном месте, о котором я забыл, полностью прекращает работу приложения, что чаще всего недопустимо. С исправлением ошибки разберусь позже. Мне нужно только понять, как это можно реализовать проще, чем оборачивать всё в try-catch